# Where does Krusader store customized shortcut keys?

Tags: krusader

I customized some shortcut keys of Krusader and want to backup its keyboard configuration to migrate to another machine of mine.

However, I couldn't figure our where Krusader stores its configuration keys. I have looked at the file `~/.config/krusaderrc` and the folder `~/.local/share/krusader/` but didn't see any keyboard configuration.

Does any know how Krusader saves the customized shortcut keys?

I'm using Krusader 2.7.2 on Linux Mint XFCE (Ubuntu based)